# Pandas seaborn data visualization

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I have this groupby commend

```
horus = df_clean.groupby(['profile_name','start_hour']).agg(
    count=('start_hour','count')).reset_index()
```

and it returns data:

| profile_name | start_hour | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | 0 | 15 |
| AAA | 1 | 13 |
| AAA | 2 | 10 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| AAA | 23 | 18 |

I am trying to make a plot similar to [this](https://seaborn.pydata.org/_images/kdeplot_5_0.png) one but

```
sns.kdeplot(data=hours, x="start_hour", hue="profile_name")
```

returns

```
The x variable is categorical, but one of ['numeric', 'datetime'] is required
```

is that my groupby fault or Am I doing the sns wrong

Comment: Does `sns.kdeplot(data=hours, x=hours["start_hour"].astype(int), hue="profile_name")` work?

Comment: I used ```sns.kdeplot(data=hours, x=hours['start_hour'].astype(int), hue="profile_name",weights="count")``` and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

I've copied your dataset & tried it on my own. You wrote everything fine, yet it seems like you have mistakenly listed the `data=` parameter's value as `**hours**` when the data variable's name is actually `**horus**`.

If that output still continues to appear, try updating seaborn by using `pip install seaborn` (add a ! at the beginning if using Jupyter NB), or alternatively write the code differently like that:

```
sns.kdeplot(x=horus['start_hour'], hue=horus['profile_name'])
```